# Python import simple_salesforce in Databricks gives: No module named cryptography.hazmat.primitives.asymmetric.ed25519

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import, azure-databricks, simple-salesforce

I'm trying to use Azure Databricks to launch Python script that imports the library: "simple_salesforce"

I have installed the library as shown on the picture bellow, please note that while installing the library the name should be "simple-salesforce" and while importing it "simple_salesforce" (just to mention that I didn't mistaken the name):
[Installation of the library](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FAx6e.png)

As shown on the picture bellow, the library was installed successfully:
[simple-salesforce installed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j9FST.png)

When try to import it in my workspace, using:

```
import simple_salesforce
```

I get the following error (see the error picture bellow):

```
ImportError: No module named 'cryptography.hazmat.primitives.asymmetric.ed25519'
```

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rK4Wn.png)

I've tried to install the "cryptography" library with the same method I used to install the other libraries (see the picture bellow), but I still get the same error:
[cryptography](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vXP2V.png)

Is there any step that I missed ?

Best regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have the library "cryptography" installed. It is very likely that you are using a Databricks runtime version of 5.5 LTS or less, with one worker.

The problem is that you have a Databricks cluster with Python3 and the notebook is running on a Python2 kernel.

**Method 1**

Check if you have python 3:

```
%sh
python3 --version
```

Then install pip3:

```
%sh
sudo apt install python3-pip
```

After that you can install "cryptography"

**Method 2**

I highly recommand this method, which consists of using 7.4 Databricks Runtime version with a minimum of 2 workers, then you will have python3 and the library "cryptography" installed by default.

You will just need to install simple-salesforce manually from the libraries part, and:

```
import simple_salesforce
```